# List comprehension with xonsh

Tags: python-3.x, xonsh

I am still new to this, but is it possible to execute multiple commands in `xonsh` using a list-comprehension syntax?

I would expect the following to create five files `file00` to `file04`, but it errors instead:

```
$ [@(['touch', 'file%02d' % i]) for i in range(5)]
............................ 
xonsh: For full traceback set: $XONSH_SHOW_TRACEBACK = True
  File "<string>", line None
SyntaxError: <xonsh-code>:1:1: ('code: @(',)
[@(['touch', 'file%02d' % i]) for i in range(5)]
 ^
```

I would expect this to work, because the following works fine:

```
$ [i for i in range(5)]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]

$ @(['touch', 'file%02d' % 3])
$ ls
file03
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way closest to your original code is to use a subprocess:

`[$[touch @('file%02d' % i)] for i in range(5)]`

To explain the need for nesting `$[ .. @(`:

- The top-level command is a list-comprehension, so we start in Python-mode;
- We want to execute a bash command (`touch`) so we need to enter subprocess-mode with `$[` (or `$(` to capture output);
- But the argument to that command requires string interpolation with Python, hence Python-mode again with `@(`.

Comment: Thanks, this is much more readable! Would it be ok for me to edit this answer with a few details in order to accept it?

Comment: Yeah! Thanks for the deeper explanation!

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you found a way to do this -- sometimes the behavior of the particular subprocess command can influence how you put it all together.

In the case of `touch`, since it can take multiple arguments, the most straightforward way to wrap this up in a list comprehension (that I can think of) is to do

`touch @([f'file_{i}' for i in range(5)])`

Comment: Thanks; what does the `f` prefix mean in `f'file_{i}'`?

Comment: f-strings (formatted string literals) were introduced in Python 3.6 [link](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.6.html#whatsnew36-pep498).
They're great.  In the above, it would be equivalent to `'file_{}'.format(i)`

Answer (score 1):

I was almost there, it is necessary to wrap the command further:

```
$ [ $(@(['touch', 'file%02d' % i])) for i in range(5)]
```

The reason for this is as follows:

- Given that the top-level command is a list-comprehension, we enter Python-mode
- We want to execute a bash command (`touch`) so we need to enter subprocess-mode with `$(`
- However, the argument to that command requires string interpolation with Python, so writing the command itself requires Python-mode, hence `@(`